# Send Hex like 0x1b 0x31 to com port in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, tcomport

I need to send Hex data like a command to my serial port using Delphi.
The Hex data like "0x1b 0x31".

What the procedure can I used ?
`writestring()` or `writebuffer()` ? How to use them ?

Comment: Which `TComPort` component do you use ? This [`TComPort`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport) component has no `WriteBuffer` method (I've grepped only version 4.11f). I'd suggest that the [tag:tcomport] tag should either be properly described (if it's about TurboPower components, or the TComPort library that I've linked in this comment, or another one), or should de destroyed as ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `TComPort` from [ComPort Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/) (sourceforge), then invoke `WriteStr()` method:

```
ComPort.WriteStr(chr($1b));
```

If you use `TApdComPort` from [TurboPower](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/) component, use the `PutChar()` method (according that command you want to send is $1b):

```
ApdComPort1.PutChar(char($1b);
```

Comment: Thanks TridenT it is work fine

Comment: Ad ComPort Library, if the aim is to send two bytes (not two chars, nor 1 char as shown in this post), you should use `Write` method. In TP there is a similar method, `PutBlock`. Except that the command should be declared as a constant, not as some magical number. But take this comment just as a note about how to do things right, hytham. It you're happy with *it works*, then you should be fine with sending your two bytes char by char in this case.